# Sharing video to Vimeo iPhone

Tags: objective-c, vimeo

I am using ESSVideoShare open framework to share video to vimeo. But I am getting stuck with it. Who can help me about that?

a, We have to setup callback url .plist file. I am okay with it. Also there is "URL identifier"(Sample app write "Vimeo Authorization URL" as placeholder) and I am not sure what it is and how to setup.

b, I am not sure if I can't login after authenticating on safari because I don't setup "URL identifier" on plist but I am getting error for "NSURLResponse *resp". Just I get nil about that.

```
        NSString *oauth_token = [retStr substringFromIndex:oauthTokenRange.location + oauthTokenRange.length];
        oauth_token = [oauth_token substringToIndex:[oauth_token rangeOfString:@"&"].location];
        NSString *oauth_verifier = [retStr substringFromIndex:verifierRange.location + verifierRange.length];

        NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:VIMEO_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL];
        OAMutableURLRequest *req = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authorizeURL
                                                                   consumer:self._oaconsumer
                                                                      token:self._requestToken
                                                                      realm:nil
                                                          signatureProvider:self._sigProv];
        [req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [req setOAuthParameterName:@"oauth_verifier" withValue:oauth_verifier];
        [req prepare];
        NSError *err = nil;
        NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:&err];
```

Please help me.
Regards,
Li.